# Lua - Using os.date

Tags: datetime, lua

I'm reading a date in a field, ex: `23/01/2015 11:04:06.265842` I would like to get `23/01/2015 11:04:06.26`.

The purpose is to compare two datetime and get the result time, for example 2.16 seconds between the two times.

Actually I'm doing : `fields["Date"]=os.date("%c", fields["frame.time_epoch"])`

`frame.time_epoch` come from a .pcap file (wireshark)

Comment: Are you asking how to chop off those final four numbers from that string? Are you asking how to get a time with similar precision from `os.date`? Something else?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

You can't get millisecond precision with `os.date` - the maximum resolution it allows is second (see it here http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html)

You could try adding it yourself:

```
local epoch = fields["frame.time_epoch"]
local milliseconds = (epoch - math.floor(epoch))*1000
fields["Date"]=("%s.%03d"):format(os.date("%c", epoch), milliseconds)
```

Comment: Sorry but I would like to do the contrary : get the time WITH the milliseconds :s    

It's for compare two times with precision

Comment: @ItMoreSimplePlease it turns out that os.date's resolution is only up to seconds. I have updated my answer with what you want